# Асинхронный режим: предупреждение об устаревании get_event_loop (). Есть ли чем заменить уже сейчас, и что это значит физически?

Tags: python

При использовании get_event_loop() все скрипты у меня работают, но выдаётся предупреждение об устаревании "DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop" ("Нет текущего цикла событий").
Как я понимаю, есть немалый шанс, что однажды в Python старше 3.10 это просто перестанет работать.
Да и вообще, я не очень люблю стиль с неустранёнными предупреждениями, они иногда устраивают весёлую жизнь потом:-)

1. Есть ли простой способ сейчас использовать что-то другое, чтобы предупреждения не было?
2. А какой физический смысл этого сообщения? Это же некий экземпляр цикла, котрый нужен - он потом и запускается в run_until_complete. Что значит: "Нет текущего цикла событий", а что же тогда есть?
   (понятно, что история с единственным циклом для единственного потока выглядит странновато, но PEP 492 прямо говорит в первых же строках, что "This PEP assumes that the asynchronous tasks are scheduled and coordinated by an Event Loop", то есть этот цикл лежит в основе).
   (Python только начал изучать, так что прошу прощения, если вопрос не очень глубокий).

Вот код для примера:

```
    import asyncio

    async def demo():
        print(await out())

    async def out():
        return "Тест"

    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() #к этой  строке предупреждение
    event_loop.run_until_complete(demo())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70303895/python-3-10-asyncio-gather-shows-deprecationwarning-there-is-no-current-event

Comment: event_loop.run_until_complete() устаревшая, рекомендуется asyncio.run()

Comment: Спасибо! Я две последние строчки заменил на asyncio.run (demo()) , этот пример работает, но по ссылке в первом комментарии говорят, что исключения пойдут - won't actually work. 
В более сложном я наткнулся на проблему, так как создавал цикл, потом - экземпляр класса Future, запускал цикл с аргументом, куда и шел этот экземпляр (ниже). Теперь надо сразу запускать с аргументом -не ясно, как экземпляр all_done создать (буду копаться:-):  
 event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        all_done = asyncio.Future()
        event_loop.run_until_complete(main(all_done))

Comment: Порылся в документации, обнаружил, что там вообще не рекомендуют экземпляры Future держать на уровне приложения. Оставил в "__main__" исключительно asyncio.run(main()), остальное убрал в async def main(). All_done создаю первым действиеи в def_main. Теперь всё работает, как и раньше, а предупреждения больше нет. Спасибо ещё раз!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итого, благодаря подсказке @Сергей Шашко, использую asyncio.run() и больше предупреждение не выдаётся. Обновлённый код - ниже. Некоторая дополнительная информация по более сложным ситуациям - в комментариях, а полная информация по циклам событий и т.д. (очень много, сложно и интересно) - на docs.python.org. (Например, страница Event Loop и связанные страницы).

```
import asyncio

async def demo():
    print(await out())

async def out():
    return "Тест"

asyncio.run(demo()) #к этой  строке нет теперь предупреждения
```