# python как получить возвращаемое значение асинхронной функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, асинхронность

Как можно получить возвращаемое значение асинхронной фукнции

```py
import asyncio

async def test(asd: bool):
    if asd is True:
        print("true")
        return True
    else:
        print("not true")
        return False

# наподобие обычной функции
res = test(asd=0)    
print(f"{res=}, {type(res)=}")
```

Comment: Написал комментарии ещё в код, а то убиться  разбираться - несколько часов потратил:-) Вот еще немного интересного по теме: <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1396448/%d0%90%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-get-event-loop-%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc>

Comment: Спасибо Вам мил человек :-)    большое СпАсИбО !!! почитаю внимательно

Comment: обалдеть сколько манипулиций  ) надо сделать, для того чтобы получить нужный результат :) Асинхронщина :()

Comment: my_response = asyncio.run(test(asd=0))      # нашел вот такое решение работающее :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Асинхронное получение результатов делается через модуль Future. Учитывая, что у вас кусок небольшой, вот пример, как я делал задачу по асинхронному чтению из файла и записи в файл (на базе другого примера из учебника Чернышова (но объяснений у него мало про этой теме)):

```
import asyncio
import functools

def callback(future): 
    future.result()
    
async def register_callbacks(all_done):
    # 5. Регистрация идёт методом, который добавляет обратный вызов 
    # (передавая туда параметры),который запускается после выполнения 
    # объекта (иными словами: при завершении работы)
    all_done.add_done_callback(functools.partial(callback))

async def main(all_done, file_name):
    # 4. Функция main ждёт, пока не выполнится регистрация callback-функции 
    # для экземпляра (именно эта часть добавлена для асинхронного  полученя 
    # результатов)- await позволяет сопрограмме отдать контроль назад в 
    # главный цикл,который содержит порядок исполнения всех сопрограмм:
    await register_callbacks(all_done)
    with open(file_name, 'r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        readed_info = f.read()
    # 6. Отрабатывает обратный вызов (future.result() получает 
    # результирующее значение, так как до него вызывается метод set_result)
    all_done.set_result(readed_info)#сюда результат read помещается

def async_write (file_name, value_holder):
    with open(file_name, 'w',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(value_holder)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # 1. Создается цикл
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        # 2. Создаётся экземпляр класса Future (он нужен для получения 
        # результата из сопрограммы): 
        all_done = asyncio.Future()
        # 3. Запускается созданный цикл и он блокирует основную часть,
        # пока не отработает функция main: 
        event_loop.run_until_complete(main(all_done, "read_.txt"))
    # После завершения всего с 3 по 6, запускается часть finally с записью в 
    # файл 
    finally: 
        string=all_done.result()
        async_write ("write_.txt", string)
        event_loop.close()
```

Вот вариант чуть попроще (без устаревшей функции):

```
import asyncio
import functools

def callback(future): 
    future.result()
    
async def register_callbacks(all_done):
    all_done.add_done_callback(functools.partial(callback))

def async_write (file_name, value_holder):
    with open(file_name, 'w',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(value_holder)

async def main():
    all_done = asyncio.Future()
    await register_callbacks(all_done)
    #print('Установка результирующего значения future - результат read')
    with open("read_.txt", 'r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        readed_info = f.read()
        all_done.set_result(readed_info)#сюда результат read помещается
    async_write ("write_.txt", all_done.result())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Что-то как-то у вас сложно всё. Какой практический смысл ждать футуру all_done, если можно просто вернуть значение из main и run_until_complete его соответственно вернёт? А если возвращать значение, то получится поведение эквивалентное asyncio.run. // Функция get_event_loop объявлена устаревшей, рекомендую уже отказываться от её использования. // Вы забыли вызвать f.close

Comment: А, ещё у вас с отступами в функции main что-то не так

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, да, при комментировании съехал "with open" - вернул на место теперь.

Comment: Функция register_callbacks полностью бессмысленная, потому что она не выполняет никаких асинхронных действий (add_done_callback синхронный и отрабатывает мгновенно)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за комментарии, обдумаю обязательно потом. 1) В целом по комментариям о смысле - я делал по примеру учебника. Возможно, взял избыточно для данной задачи, возможно в учебнике что-то излишне. 2) f.close в принципе, автоматически же выполнится в конце силами event_loop.close(), нет?  3) да, устаревшая, поместил ещё пример без неё чуть переделанный.

Comment: «вариант чуть попроще» тоже бессмысленный, в нём вместо `all_done.result()` можно просто использовать `readed_info` напрямую, да и вообще в примере никто нигде не выполняет никаких асинхронных действий (впрочем, пример автора вопроса тоже бессмысленный)

Comment: 2) Нет, f.close никто кроме вас не вызовет: если вы запустите свой пример в режиме отладки, то скорее всего получите предупреждение о незакрытом файле

Comment: (а хотя нет, тут же стоит `with open` — он-то и закроет файл, а строка f.close получается просто бессмысленной)

Comment: @andreymal, 1) "пример автора вопроса тоже бессмысленный" - вы посмотрели в учебник, и там много лишнего, или моя ссылка на учебник смысла не несёт? 2) Спасибо, верно, удалил f.close.

Comment: 1) Я не вижу здесь ссылок на учебники, я смотрю здесь в код и вижу его бессмысленность; 2) Питон никогда не закрывает файлы сам (точнее, в CPython можно понадеяться на сборщик мусора, но лучше не надо), файл (и другие внешние ресурсы вроде сокетов) всегда должен закрываться явно и вручную через close или with (и асинхронность здесь ни при чём)

Comment: @andreymal, я в самом начале написал, что это из Чернышова. Добавлю слово "учебник" теперь. 2)  "Питон никогда не закрывает файлы сам" - это не так, файлы Python закрывает сборщиком мусора. См. того же Чернышова, да и в других местах встречал эту информацию. Но учту, буду закрывать для надёжности.

Comment: 2) Сборщик мусора в PyPy ничего не закрывает. Да и даже в CPython сборщик мусора хоть и закрывает, но кидается предупреждением о том, что программист творит глупость (выше я уже писал про режим отладки)

Comment: Я буду закрывать, я же уже пообещал. Я относительно "никогда" написал. А режим отладки (прямо определение такое не гуглится) - это запуск в PyCharm пошаговый?

Comment: Под «режимом отладки» я подразумеваю запуск с включенными предупреждениями (`python -Wd`) и [включенной отладкой asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html) (через аргумент `debug=True` или переменную окружения `PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1`)

Comment: Полистал Чернышёва — да, у него точно такой же бессмысленный код (и местами вредные советы). Такое ощущение, будто ему никто не сказал, что наличие `async` не превращает магически функцию в асинхронную и что `run_until_complete` умеет возвращать значение

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо огромное за все комментарии!

Comment: Раз уж я начал тут люто критиковать всех подряд, то для полноты отмечу ещё один момент: после завершения работы run_until_complete (когда завершается выполнение таска main) внутри event loop'а могут остаться другие незавершённые таски (запущенные через loop.create_task или типа того), и если они не завершат свою работу — это не очень хорошо, потому что они могут не выполнить какой-нибудь очень важный код завершения работы. [...]

Comment: [...] Для корректного завершения asyncio.run вызывает cancel у каждой оставшейся таски и дожидается их полного завершения (запускает ещё один run_until_complete). Чернышёв этого не делает, и хотя в его примитивных примерах это не вызывает проблем, в более сложном реальном коде станет плохо. (Есть ещё shutdown_asyncgens, но я пока сам не до конца понял, что конкретно он делает)

Answer (score 3):

```
import asyncio


async def test(asd: bool):
    if asd is True:
        print("true")
        return True
    else:
        print("not true")
        return False


my_response = asyncio.run(test(asd=0))   # нашел такое решение работающее :)
```

Comment: Это отлично, только советую проверить на совокупности случаев, что это не случайность. Полагаю, что "моя" версия рассчитана на кучу процессов, асинхронно мешающих друг другу. Если у вас, например, два процесса, раз в час к ресурсу вывода на секунду обращающихся, то вам все это нагороможление долго не пригодится:-)

Comment: все верно говорите, все зависит и от наличия и других процессов/асин.функций и как это все в комплексе работает и корректно ли  ) !!!